# Application for creating images that look hand written/hand drawn

Tags: software-recommendation

My wife recently installed the snapseed application on her iPad, and I really like how the help screens for each of the functions snapseed offers comes across as being hand written/hand drawn.

Short of actually hand writing and/or hand drawing stuff and scanning it in, does anyone know of an application that would provide me with the ability to create similar images for using in presentations and such? I'm by no means an artist, and my hand writing sucks, so scanning stuff in is out of the question. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to create kind-of-comics in Ubuntu using Scribus --> http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus and looking for different fonts that may resemble handwriting. So you could create these images in this program, or in Inkscape / GIMP.

This is an example of how to get a font that resembles handwriting running in your system --> http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-rufscript-a-nice-handwriting-font-in-ubuntu-hardyintrepid.html

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! Rufscript is perfect, and GIMP will work great once I can steady my hand out with the mouse and free-form some drawings. Scribus will also come in handy, but for something else. :-)

Comment: I'm glad this helped :)

Answer (score 1):

If you start **inkscape**, select the font tool, write a little bit of text, keep it marked, open the font-selection-tool, and iterate - most conveniently by the arrow keys - through the fonts, you will find a lot of fonts which look like hand written.

You can then create some simple graphics like the arrows above, more complicated the pointing hand, and insert them where you need to, while it is easy to rotate them, zoom in or out.

Maybe there is a good gallery of pre build icons? With

```
 locate gallery | grep svg
```

You may search your harddrive. I found some svg(z)-graphics (SVG-Zipped), the preferred file format for inkscape, in  */usr/share/icons/oxygen/scalable/apps/* only, but not those arrows, hands. Maybe you can google for a free svg-gallery?

You can import an bitmap image wiht inkscape like the photo in your example, and paint on top of that.